# If a differentiable function is defined on a closed interval, can I expand it with Taylor formula about the extrema?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Consider a differentiable function $f: [a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$. Does it make sense to find the taylor series expansion of such function about the points $a$ and $b$? Or does it work only for $x\in [a,b]$?